# Using URLRewriteFilter to version CSS

Tags: spring, gwt, url-rewriting

I am looking into using URLRewriteFilter to version CSS files in my GWT application. The CSS are spread out all over so the incoming request can of any arbitrary form. I just want to do the following

if a request is of form http://x.y.z:8080/blah/1/2/R01_local.css I want to serve http://x.y.z:8080/blah/1/2/local.css (ie stripping out the prefix for the file)

The URLRewrite filter in question is http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

I am not sure how to use it to construct a regex which would be of form replace (exp1)R01_(exp2).css with (exp1)(exp2).css

The application in question is in GWT/Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you know you'll never have "R01_" in any other part of your URLs:

```
<rule>
    <from>^(.*)R01_(.*).css$</from>
    <to>$1$2.css</to>
</rule>
```

Probably better to make it more specific, but that's dependent on your directory organization and what makes sense in context. Example:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/blah/(.*)R01_(.*).css$</from>
    <to>/blah/$1$2.css</to>
</rule>
```